# Unable to hit AWS api gateway endpoint from EC2 instance in the same VPC using a resource policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-api-gateway, amazon-vpc

I have an ec2 instance inside a VPC, and I'd like to limit access to my api gateway to just that VPC. It seems like this should be really simple based on the examples they give, but for some reason I can't access it from my ec2 instance with this policy:

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement":
  [
    {
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
      "Resource": "execute-api:*",
      "Condition":
      {
        "StringNotEquals":
        {
          "aws:sourceVpc": "vpc-******"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
      "Resource": "execute-api:*"
    }
  ]
}
```

It seems very straight-forward, but attempting to hit an endpoint gives me this error: `User: anonymous is not authorized to perform: execute-api:Invoke on resource: arn:aws:execute-api:...`

Other things I've tried:

- Changing the "Resource" value to "execute-api/*"
- Using the arn value as the Resource instead of "execute-api..."
- Switching the order of the Deny and Allow statements
- Just using an allow statement like so:

```
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "arn:***",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:SourceVpc": "vpc-*****"
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Also, I am able to hit the endpoint if I remove the policy all together, if that's relevant

Comment: Is the Api Gateway Private or Regional?

Comment: It was Regional, but I've since switched to Private

Comment: For Private Api Gateway you need a VPC Endpoint configured. Can you show that config?

Comment: Can I do this without using a Private Gateway? I've created a VPC Endpoint, but I haven't had any luck. I'lll see if I can find the config for it, but I'd rather do it the simplest way possible

Comment: It depends on what you want to achieve. Do you want an Regional Api Gateway and restrict traffic from a particular VPC?